# Need to convert single rows in multiple rows per month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a period column which needs to be split into multiple rows per month

The table has lots of records like this:

```
ID, PERIOD,        AMOUNT
1,  201812-201902, 300.00
2,  201804-201903, 1150.00
3,  201901-201902, 200.00
```

I need to following query result:

```
1, 12-2018, 100.00
1, 01-2019, 100.00
1, 02-2019, 100.00

2, 04-2018, 95.83
2, 05-2018, 95.83
2, 06-2018, 95.83
2, 07-2018, 95.83
2, 08-2018, 95.83
2, 09-2018, 95.83
2, 10-2018, 95.83
2, 11-2018, 95.83
2, 12-2018, 95.83
2, 01-2019, 95.83
2, 02-2019, 95.83
2, 03-2019, 95.83

3, 01-2019, 100.00
3, 02-2019, 100.00
```

How to achieve this in MS-Access SQL?

Comment: Does that expected result match the sample table data?

Comment: I think this will need VBA writing records to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this with a series of queries (that I had on hand):

Save this as **Ten**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Save this as **MonthDateRange**:

```
PARAMETERS 
    [DateStart] DateTime, [DateEnd] DateTime;
SELECT 
    [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000 AS Id, [DateStart] AS DateStart, [DateEnd] AS DateEnd, DateAdd("m",[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000,[DateStart]) AS DateMonth
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, Ten AS Ten_1, Ten AS Ten_2, Ten AS Ten_3, Ten AS Ten_4, Ten AS Ten_5, Ten AS Ten_6
WHERE 
    (((DateAdd("m",[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000,[DateStart]))<=DateAdd("m",DateDiff("m",[DateStart],DateAdd("d",-1,[DateEnd])),[DateStart])) AND ((Ten_0.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1) AND ((Ten_1.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\10) AND ((Ten_2.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\100) AND ((Ten_3.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1000) AND ((Ten_4.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\10000) AND ((Ten_5.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\100000) AND ((Ten_6.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1000000));
```

Then build your final query using your table *Periods*:

```
SELECT 
    Periods.Id, MonthsDateRange.DateMonth AS Period, Periods.Amount
FROM 
    Periods, MonthsDateRange
WHERE 
    (((MonthsDateRange.DateMonth) Between CDate(Format(Left([Period],6),"@@@@\/@@")) And CDate(Format(Right([Period],6),"@@@@\/@@"))))
ORDER BY 
    Periods.Id, MonthsDateRange.DateMonth;
```

Now, call this passing a start and end date beyond your range of periods, say 2000-01-01 and 2020-01-01, and the output will be:

[image: Output]

To have the amount split over the periods, include a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    Periods.Id, MonthsDateRange.DateMonth AS Period, 
    [Amount]/(Select Count(*) From MonthsDateRange As T Where T.DateMonth Between CDate(Format(Left([Period],6),"@@@@/@@")) And CDate(Format(Right([Period],6),"@@@@/@@"))) AS AmountPeriod
FROM 
    Periods, MonthsDateRange
WHERE 
    (((MonthsDateRange.DateMonth) Between CDate(Format(Left([Period],6),"@@@@\/@@")) And CDate(Format(Right([Period],6),"@@@@\/@@"))))
ORDER BY 
    Periods.Id, MonthsDateRange.DateMonth;
```

to obtain this output:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, it works perfectly. I had to make a small change because of this error:

circular reference caused by alias in query definition select list.

So I changed this in the: MonthsDateRange query:

[DateStart] AS DS, [DateEnd] AS DE

Thank you so much!
BR, Emphyrio.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Comment: And the generated output is, of course, exactly as requested.

Comment: I am sorry, I made an error in my question.  I see now, the output should of course have been as I have edited it in my question above. How should I adjust the query to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a subquery to count - see extended answer, please.

Comment: Great! It works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Then please mark as answered.

Comment: How do i mark a question as answered. I do not see the option anywhere.

Comment: That's easy: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)